# Initialize optional @AppStorage property with non-nil value

Tags: swiftui, property-wrapper, appstorage

I need an optional `@AppStorage` String property (for a `NavigationLink` selection, which required optional), so I declared

```
@AppStorage("navItemSelected") var navItemSelected: String?
```

I need it to start with a default value that's non-nil, so I tried:

```
@AppStorage("navItemSelected") var navItemSelected: String? = "default"
```

but that doesn't compile.

I also tried:

```
init() {
    if navItemSelected == nil { navItemSelected = "default" }
}
```

But this just overwrites the actual persisted value whenever the app starts.

Is there a way to start it with a default non-nil value and then have it persisted as normal?

Comment: `Optional` is not plist type so cannot be stored in AppStorage, you need to solve this at `NavigationLink` side, say by introducing inline Binding checking conditionally value of AppStorage.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple demo of possible approach based on inline `Binding` (follow-up of my comment above).

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoAppStoreNavigation: View {
    static let defaultNav = "default"
    @AppStorage("navItemSelected") var navItemSelected = Self.defaultNav

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button("Go Next") {
                navItemSelected = "next"
            }.background(
                NavigationLink(isActive: Binding(
                    get: { navItemSelected != Self.defaultNav },
                    set: { _ in }
                ), destination: {
                    Button("Return") {
                        navItemSelected = Self.defaultNav
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        navItemSelected = Self.defaultNav   // << for the case of `<Back`
                    }
                }) { EmptyView() }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@AppStorage` is a wrapper for `UserDefaults`, so you can simply register a default the old-fashioned way:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["navItemSelected" : "default"])
```

You will need to call `register(defaults:)` *before* your view loads, so I’d recommend calling it in your App’s init or in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

Answer (score 0):

[This hacking with swift article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper) has an example of setting a default to a non-optional string value while using @AppStorage. This works for me with a boolean value as well.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("username") var username: String = "Anonymous"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome, \(username)!")

            Button("Log in") {
                username = "@twostraws"
            }
        }
    }
}
```